# Break collection of integers into contiguous ranges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say that I have a large collection of ordered integers with holes as a result of some aggregation query in Neo4j:

`[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,45,46,47,48,....]`

What I need is to break this collection into collection of ranges like this:
`[1-5, 7-10, 45-48,...]`

In the case of a collection with no holes - it's easy to convert a list to a range by finding min and max elements and returning them.

With the given collection with holes I would like to apply some kind of a map/reduce function which, for example, compares difference between two elements with `1`. And if the difference is greater than one, end with generating one sub-collection and start collecting another one. Then aggregate subcollections with min/max functions to get a collection of ranges.

It seems that I can't find any suitable tool neither in standard Neo4j functions, nor in its APOC extension.

Any suggestions on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using two reduce functions, like this:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,45,46,47,48] AS array
WITH array, reduce(
    data = { indexes: [0], prev: array[0] }, 
    x IN range(1,size(array)) | 
    { indexes: data.indexes + CASE WHEN array[x] - data.prev > 1 THEN [x] ELSE [] END, prev: array[x] }
) AS data
WITH array, data.indexes AS idxs
WITH array, reduce(finalArray = [], x IN range(0, size(idxs)) | finalArray + [CASE WHEN x + 1 < size(idxs) THEN array[idxs[x]] + "-" + array[idxs[x+1] - 1] ELSE array[idxs[x]] + "-" + array[size(array) - 1] END]) AS ranges
RETURN array, ranges[0..-1]
```

In this query, we first calculate the indexes where the holes exist, and then using those indexes, we calculate the ranges. However, the array must be sorted in ascending order, for this query to give correct output.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Charchit! This is exactly what I need and it works like a charm. I underestimated reduce() capabilities at the first glance.

Comment: Take a look at apoc.coll and it's set of functions for collections.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single `REDUCE`:

```
WITH [1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,45,46,47,48,50] AS array
RETURN array, REDUCE(
    r = [array[0]], 
    i IN RANGE(1, size(array)-1) | 
    CASE WHEN array[i] - array[i-1] > 1
      THEN r[0..-1] + (r[-1] + '-' + array[i-1]) + TOSTRING(array[i])
      ELSE r END
) AS ranges
```

The result:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════╕
│array                                        │ranges                               │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50]│["1-1", "3-5", "7-10", "45-48", "50"]│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Or, if you want each range in a map:

```
WITH [1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,45,46,47,48,50] AS array
RETURN array, REDUCE(
    r = [{from: array[0], to: array[0]}], 
    i IN range(1, size(array)-1) | 
    CASE WHEN array[i] - array[i-1] > 1
      THEN r[0..-1] + {from: r[-1].from, to: array[i-1]} + {from: array[i], to: array[i]}
      ELSE r END
) AS ranges
```

With the result:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│array                                        │ranges                                                  │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50]│[{from: 1, to: 1}, {from: 3, to: 5}, {from: 7, to: 10}, │
│                                             │{from: 45, to: 48}, {from: 50, to: 50}]                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Looks nice and neat. Took me some time to understand the code. Reworked my query closer to your approach. Thanks a lot!